# WMV Playback using Phonon::VideoWidget and Flip4Mac fails in 32-bit builds

Tags: c++, macos, qt, wmv, phonon

My application needs to run on Windows and Mac OS X and display various kinds of media files, such as videos and Adobe Flash content. After installing the Flip4Mac codec, I can play WMV video using Phonon on the Mac. In order to support Flash via the Flash plugin in a QWebView, I need to build a 32-bit binary. But when I do that, WMV playback no longer works. The app hangs, uses 100% CPU and memory usage keeps growing.

So, basically if I build a 32-bit binary, I don't have WMV (and a crashed/frozen app) and if I build a 64-bit (or universal) binary, I don't have Flash.

Any suggestions for workarounds/fixes?